# Website Login issue in Azure Linux Servers

Tags: java, linux, azure

I deployed my website in Azure Virtual Machine(RedHat8).

I faced an issue while login into a website(java based), It has taken too much time to login(taken more than 950s), or while refreshing the page it can be redirected to the home page, and sometimes it has login very quickly(in 5s).

The Same project I deployed in AWS and GCP Linux servers there is no login issue. I followed the same process for every Deployment.

I don't know why the login issue coming in Azure servers.

Please anyone help regarding this issue. It is very helpful to me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is it a firewall issue?

Comment: Hi @Jatin, I enabled the required ports in the firewall. I think it's not a firewall issue. If in case it's a firewall issue I am not able to access the website in the browser.                       if you feel anything I am missing, Please suggest me clear this issue. It's very helpful.            Thank you.